# Extracting 3D netcdf variable from lists within nested loop in R

Tags: r, for-loop, netcdf

Say I have 10 model configurations of *n* timesteps for 3 different sites, producing a total 30 netcdf files I want to open and manipulate. I can open the 30 files such as

```
require(ncdf4)

allfiles= list() 
nmod=10     
nsites=3    

for (i in 1:nmod) {
allfiles[[i]] = list(nc_open(paste0('Model',i,'siteA.nc')),
                     nc_open(paste0('Model',i,'siteB.nc')),
                     nc_open(paste0('Model',i,'siteC.nc')))
}
```

When querying the class of what was opened, I have

> class(allfiles)
>
> [1] "list"
>
> class(allfiles[[1]][[1]])
>
> [1] "ncdf4"

as expected.
Now what I would like to do is extract the values from a variable in the files such that

```
var=list()
for (i in 1:nmod) {
  for (j in 1:nsites) {
    var[[i]][[j]] <- ncvar_get(allfiles[[i]][[j]],"var1") 
    nc_close(allfiles[[i]][[j]])
   }}
```

but I get this error message:

```
 `Error in *tmp*[[i]] : subscript out of bounds`
```

If I try

```
 var[[i]] <- ncvar_get(allfiles[[i]][[j]],"var1")
```

it (understandbly) only produces a list of 10 model configurations at one site, i.e. `var[[1]][[1]][1]` prints out the value of the variable at model configuration 1, site A, timestep 1 but `var[[1]][[2]]` doesn't exist.
How can I declare `var` in the above loop so that it contains all the values for all models, all sites and all timesteps (e.g. for `var[[1]][[2]][1]` to exist)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your original version where the error occurs, in the first inner loop, you try to do something: `var[[1]][[1]] <- something`, but `var[[1]]` doesn't exist, and `R` doesn't know what to do, so I guess the following thing should work, you set `var[i] <- list()` before you do `var[[i]][[j]] <- something`:

```
var=list()
for (i in 1:nmod) {
var[i] <- list()
  for (j in 1:nsites) {
    var[[i]][[j]] <- ncvar_get(allfiles[[i]][[j]],"var1") 
    nc_close(allfiles[[i]][[j]])
  }
}
```

For example, if you do:

```
var <- list()
for (i in 1:10) {
    for (j in 1:10) {
        var[[i]][[j]] <- 1
    }
}
```

Then the same error happens. But if you set `var[[i]] <- list()` before carrying out the inner loop like this:

```
var <- list()
for (i in 1:10) {
    var[[i]] <- list()
    for (j in 1:10) {
        var[[i]][[j]] <- 1
    }
}
```

Then the problem will be solved.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to work it out and also for your MWE, I hadn't thought of something so to the point!